# When I try update one of my users profiles it updates mine instead

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the code I have in the User Model

```
public function update_account($first, $last, $email, $phone, $address, $company, $vat, $notes) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE users 
                SET name = ?, surname = ?, email = ?, phone = ?, 
                    address = ?, company = ?, vat = ?, notes = ? 
                WHERE id = ?", 
                    array($first, $last, $email, $phone, 
                          $address, $company, $vat, $notes, 
                          $this->session->id));
}
```

Here is the code that is in my User Controller

```
public function settings() {
    if ($this->user->is_logged()) {
        iF ($_POST) {
            $first_name = $this->input->post('ipt_first');
            $last_name = $this->input->post('ipt_last');
            $email = $this->input->post('ipt_email');
            $phone = $this->input->post('ipt_phone');
            $address = $this->input->post('ipt_address');
            $company = $this->input->post('ipt_company');
            $vat = $this->input->post('ipt_vat');
            $notes = $this->input->post('ipt_notes');
            $this->user->update_account($first_name, $last_name, $email, $phone, $address, $company, $vat, $notes);
        }
        if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
            if ($this->user->is_admin($this->session->email)) {
                $udata['uinfo'] = $this->user->details($this->uri->segment(3));
                load_content('user/settings', $udata);
            }
        } else {
            $udata['uinfo'] = $this->user->details($this->session->id);
            load_content('user/settings', $udata);
        }
    } else {
        redirect();
    }
}
```

Basically I need it to only update their information if its a customer and if you are an admin (perm level 1 in mysql 0 is default to customer) set my own settings or someone elses if I am viewing their settings page.

My HTML Form works as I can update my own details with the code above however when viewing a customers settings I can't override them as it changes my own.

I hope I've added enough detail, if not please be fair as I'm relatively new to programming and stackoverflow. Kind regards, and thanks for the help offered.

Comment: Because `$this->session->id` will be YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `update_account` function, you use `$this->session->id` in the where clause - this will always be your id.

try to send the id of the user you want to change with the rest of the data, pass that to the `update_account` function and use the correct id for the update